# Get last contract list

Tags: tokens, list

Hi i'm trying to get last contract with api i do :

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=list&apikey=xxxx

but result is :

{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Error! Missing Or invalid Action name"}

how to do? thx.

Comment: There is no action `list` in module `contract` - https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts What do you mean with "to get last contract"?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the url you have apikey=xxxx. You should create your own API key on etherscan and replce xxxx with it.

Comment: yes i idid it was just for the exemple and not expose my api key to public

Comment: I see, so you are trying to get the last contract of block or transaction or what?

Comment: Maybe check etherscan's docs to see what endpoints their api implements (https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/)

Comment: the api endpoint does not help for this nothing showing how these kinds of websites do to get the last contracts https://blockcheng.com/

Comment: You can get the verified contracts here: https://etherscan.io/contractsVerified if you want to get all the contracts you could just get all transactions of the last block and check which are contract deploys